# How could I modify/alter setup content in typo3 template?

Tags: typo3

I am a newbie to typo3. I have installed 10.2.2. Typo3 does not allow me to alter or modify content in template setup. It seems something I might have missed in installation. I am a window user. Kindly guide me to sort out this one. I have attached the screenshot below:

[image: Template/setup]

Comment: There seems to be something very wrong. I guess some JavaScript could not be loaded. Could you have a look at your browser developer tools to see if there are 404?
To be better able to help you, you might want to amend your question with the steps you followed to install TYPO3.
To play around with TYPO3, IMHO the easiest and most failsafe way is installing docker and ddev and following the TYPO3 quickstart here: https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/users/cli-usage/ - this will install a TYPO3 v9 which is the current LTS version and I would recommend it.

Comment: actually this happens to me as well when i try to do somthing on the Backend ON MY MAC. The same happens by RTE.

Comment: @JonasEberle Sorry to say this, I do not have privilege to install Docker because I am running Windows 7 PC. Is there any alternative plan for this? Also give me idea to solve  "Oops, an error occurred!" problem.

Comment: @MithunJack Ooops, an error occured! Is a general message in the frontend when [FE][debug]=0 is set in settings. The full error will be in your log (./var/log/). Have a look here for error handling in TYPO3: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/ErrorAndExceptionHandling/Index.html

Comment: @AristeidisKaravas wrote on Slack that "i can now confirm that is only on TYPO3v10, only on the template module (see picture above) and by the browsers that i have checked it: Chrome, Firefox, Safari. I checked it on my MACBOOK Pro" - So you are unlikely to have that problem on TYPO3 v9.

Comment: @JonasEberle Yeah! that's right.. TYPO3 v9 is perfectly alright.

Comment: Maybe you stumbled upon this issue https://forge.typo3.org/issues/89124 ?

Comment: @JonasEberle  I'm finally ok with installation, even mastered the setup process. Now I have a big confusion over typo3 crud. I am now running a bootstrap extension for typo3. If I want to develop a CRUD operation, do I need to create any new extension or I can start creating files alongside with my bootstrap package. I need some effective advice to make it happen with 10 days.